# Need triangulation in haskell

Tags: haskell, geometry

I look for code to computer a triangulation (prefered Delaunay triangulation) in Haskell (oder callable from Haskell) or for a Voronoi diagram.

I have checked various packages I found with hackage, but they seem to be old and do not compile with current ghc (delaunay, triangulation)  or  not well documented that I cannot get them to compile (e.g. hgeometry).

What should I use? Any pointers would be appreciated!

I currently have with `hgeometry`:

```
qs :: [Point 2 (RealNumber 5)]
qs = [Point2  0 0, Point2  1 1, Point2  0 2, Point2  2 2]

qsne = fromList qs   
t1 = delaunayTriangulation qsne
```

and get the error I cannot understand:

```
Code/Lib/TryDelaunay.hs:65:28: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Point 2 (RealNumber 5)’
                     with ‘Point 2 r :+ p’
      Expected type: NonEmpty (Point 2 r :+ p)
        Actual type: NonEmpty (Point 2 (RealNumber 5))
    • In the first argument of ‘delaunayTriangulation’, namely ‘qsne’
      In the expression: delaunayTriangulation qsne
      In an equation for ‘t1’: t1 = delaunayTriangulation qsne
    • Relevant bindings include
        t1 :: Triangulation p r (bound at Code/Lib/TryDelaunay.hs:65:1)
```

Comment: I haven't tried `hgeometry` myself, but it looks pretty comprehensive and maintained. Why don't you ask about getting that to compile? (That would also avoid _off-topic: product recommendation_.)

Comment: I have tried hgeometry - because I had the same impression: comprehensive -  but cannot get any of the examples to compile and run - probably for lack of documentation and the sheer size and complexity. I would prefer something simpler.

Comment: It's not like you need to use everything from the entire package... the [`delauneyTriangulation`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hgeometry-0.14/docs/Algorithms-Geometry-DelaunayTriangulation-DivideAndConquer.html#v:delaunayTriangulation) function itself is just a function, and it doesn't seem to be that much different from e.g. Python's SciKit implementation.

Comment: I tried that one but cannot find out how to construct the input. it should have a a non-empty list of `newtype Point (d :: Nat) (r :: *) = Point { toVec :: Vector d r }`. Make a list of `Point 2 Float`, but then in `delaunayTriangulation`  I get the error `Couldn't match type ‘Point 2 Float’ with ‘Point 2 r :+ p’` and I do not see how to create this. I tried `Point 2 (RealNumber 5)` but then 5 is not a Nat. I do not understandt the use of `:+` here.

Comment: I did a library a couple of years ago which performs the Delaunay tessellation in arbitrary dimension (up to 9 I think): <https://github.com/stla/qhull>. It is based on the C library **Qhull**.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: very interesting. has all what I currently require. What is the relation to the qhull package in hackage?  seems older? - I downloaded and it compiled (thanks to using stack and a test seem to run). Have you tried to update it to a newer version of the compiler (it seems to use ghc 8.2.2). I tried compilation with 8.7.10 and failed.

Comment: I didn't know the qhull package on hackage. It looks old. I didn't use my package for a couple of years. Now I'm using Qhull in R.

Comment: Wow I looked at my package. This was good work. It would be nice to refresh it.

Comment: I will this week check if I want to put work into it to update it; your help will be appreciated. can we move this to email? - yo find it on my homepage.

Comment: Ok, I'll send you a mail. I've just started another package for 2D Delaunay: <https://github.com/stla/hcdt>. It works with ghc 9. It will also deal with the *constrained* 2D triangulation later. Don't forget to tag my name, I didn't receive a notification of your latest comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`:+`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hgeometry-combinatorial-0.14/docs/Data-Ext.html#t::-43-) is just a type for "annotated points". You can attach any data you like to each of the points, without affecting the triangulation. (You see that it doesn't affect it from the fact that the type variable `p` is completely unconstrained, i.e. the function has no way to take these values into account, it can only store them / reference them from the resulting data structure.)

If you don't want to add any annotations... well, you can always add an annotation that doesn't actually contain any information, by writing `p :+ ()`. Or if you already have a (nonempty-) list `qsne`, you can use

```
  fmap (:+()) qsne
```

to make it conformant to `delauneyTriangulation`.

Comment: Thank you - now it works. The function `delaunayTriangulation` does not much with the annotaions to the points; they are not reported in the list of vertices (only in the list of input points).  - Do you want to post an answer I can accept or should I answer the question?

Comment: It is already an answer. (But if you don't accept, I'll stay on 111,111 reputation a bit longer, so that's ok...)

Answer (score 1):

I post here the full code and hope it helps others. It lists all the language extensions I found necessary and the imports required (with the dependencies). Suggestions for improvements are welcome!

---

--
-- Module      :   an example how to use the triangulation from hgeometry

```
-- dependencies:
--  - hgeometry 
--   - hgeometry-combinatorial
--   - linear
-- all language extensions are explicitely in the file

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wno-missing-signatures #-}

module Lib.TryDelaunay 
     where

import Data.Geometry ( Point(Point2) )  
import Algorithms.Geometry.DelaunayTriangulation.DivideAndConquer
    ( delaunayTriangulation )
import Data.Ext ( type (:+)(..) )
import Data.List.NonEmpty ( NonEmpty, fromList )
import Algorithms.Geometry.DelaunayTriangulation.Types (toPlanarSubdivision)

qs :: [Point 2 Float :+ Char]
qs = [(Point2  0 0) :+ 'a' , Point2  1.5 1.5 :+ 'b' , Point2  0 2  :+ 'c', Point2  2 0  :+ 'd']

-- qsne = fmap (:+()) $ fromList qs
qsne :: NonEmpty (Point 2 Float :+ Char)
qsne =  fromList qs

t1 = delaunayTriangulation qsne 
g1 = toPlanarSubdivision t1
-- NonEmpty.fromList [4, 5]
-- p2 :: Point 2 Int
mainDel1:: IO ()
mainDel1 = do 
    print.unwords  $ ["qs", show qs]
    print.unwords  $  ["t1", show t1]
```